# How to pass argument to the method definition of `[]`?

Tags: ruby, methods

How can I pass an argument to the definition of a singleton method of `[]` on `A`, in other words `A['some_argument']`?

```
class A
  def self.[]
    # some_argument
  end
end
```

Comment: The docs for [methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html) contain examples for both, `[]` and `[]=` (you have to scroll down a bit)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just as to any other method, using argument list:

```
class A 
  def self.[](arg)
    puts arg
  end  
end  

A[1]
# => 1
```

Comment: What can be reason that we can define custom method named as `[]`  but not by other `<>` , `{}` or `()` ?

Comment: @ray: how can you tell method `{}` from a block? As for `<>` - good question, maybe nobody needed it, that's all.

Comment: Maybe they're saving it for the time they introduce static typing and generics into ruby :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev True, saw doc provided by Stefan in question's comment & got that it is in-built

Comment: @ray many programming languages use square brackets to reference elements of collections, so `arr[1]` or `str[1]` are common constructs. Something like `obj<1>` on the other hand would be quite unusual. And `obj{1}` / `obj(1)` would infer with block arguments / method invocation.

Comment: @Stefan Also `obj<1>` would clash with normal less and greater methods. Consider `class C; def <(other); 42; end; end` and `C.new <100> 5` returns `true`.

Comment: The definition isn't really like other methods. Otherwise, you'd need to call `A.[] 1` or `A.[](1)`.

Comment: The **definition** is like other methods. The **usage** is different, because of syntax sugar mentioned above.

Answer (score 7):

Good answers are already given, but I think they miss to mention an important point.

The method `[]`, when used ordinarily in the form `foo[params]` is actually in syntax sugar form. The underlying method name is `[]`, and calling it in the underlying form would be `foo.[](params)`.

Syntax sugar plays around with syntax, and transforms a method call in the form `foo[params]` into `foo.[](params)`. But that does not work in method definition, so you have to define such method in the underlying form, not in the syntax sugar form.

Answer (score 5):

```
class A
  def self.[](*args)
    puts args
  end
end

> A[1,2,3]
   1
   2
   3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also implement "set" functionality

```
class A
  def self.[]=(key, value)
    puts "#{key} = #{value}"
  end
end

A['one'] = '1'
# one = 1
```